# Interpolating to get rid of NANs and contour plot

Tags: python, interpolation, contour

I have these arrays that I need to interpolate and make the smoothest possible interpolation:

```
x = time
y = height
z = latitude

print np.shape(x)
print np.shape(y)
print np.shape(z)
```

Result:

```
(99, 25)
(99, 25)
(99, 25)
```

y is altitude and it's not uniform. It has a bunch of nan's and even though they're all the same size (a variable n_alt with the number of altitudes, which is for this example 99).

x is time and it's uniform all the way through (all the values in one column of that array are the same).

z is latitude and it's the actual 'z' and it's an array with the same number of rows as the number of time points and same number of rows as the altitude points.

I want to interpolate in 2D (the data set has series of nans in both x and y directions) to fill the gaps on the data, since several files will cover a certain altitude range and not others

My questions are:

1) is there a good way to fill the gaps the 2 directions while making the grid uniform (the idea is to plot that and also save the interpolated data (x,y and z) into a new file as well)?

2) what's a good way to contour plot the data with the shape I mentioned earlier (tried plt.contour, but it doesn't give a satisfactory result just plotting that straight up)?

Thanks y'all

Edit:

I believe this will illustrate the question better:

[X: Time, Y: Altitude, Z: Latitude or Longitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnT6J.png)

I essentially want to fill up the white space (I understand the consequences of extrapolations and all, but I just want, at this point, to have an algorithm that works. The blue dots is my grid and the color plot is just a normal plt.contour (no interpolation done). I want to make such that I have blue dots all over the plot area.

Answer (score 0):

Rafael! With respect to your interpolation question, I can explain the math if you want to manually come up with an interpolation function, but there is an existing resource you might want to look into: scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator
(see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html)

If I have misunderstood your issue, another interpolation method from the class might be appropriate: see, scipy.interpolate

For plotting the 3d surface, https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html might help guide you! Let me know if this helps! Just comment if you would like me to expand! Hopefully those are the resources you were looking for!

Comment: Generally, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata if you want looser constraints on regularity

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for this comment and the guidance. I'm gonna try to implement something and let you know about my results. Thanks a lot and will be back soon with a question or a solution :)

Comment: Sweet! Keep me posted. Happy to improve on my answer to earn an upvote or accepted solution. Best of luck!

Comment: Hey Peter, I edited the question... maybe this'll make it more graspable. Also, let me know if it helps to have the actual data. Thanks for your help mate!

Comment: Maybe a subset of the data? And what you would expect as output for that subset? Do you want to also "interpolate" to the edges of that plot? In that case, you aren't really interpolating at all since it isn't some combination of nearby points, it is a model based projection out to some unknown space (extrapolation)

Comment: You are right, it's a combination of both extrap and interp. I can get more points beyond 120 seconds, but I want to have the tool ready to calculate regardless of that being possible or not. Also, the interpolation is very necessary too in this case, since I do have data gaps between existing points (as you said, combination of nearby points). If I can interpolate enough to make the vertical blue dots to be as often as 1 second and the alt resolution to be around 200 m instead of 1 km, I would be happy with it. This is a very linear dataset with regard to time (Lat vs Time is almost linear).

Comment: Ok yeah maybe this will help? https://plot.ly/python/interpolation-and-extrapolation-in-2d/

Comment: Otherwise, I’ll need data, the code you have tried so far, and why the results aren’t what you’d expect. You could straight up copy and paste sections of this page if the challenge is as I understand it! https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html

Comment: Okay! Time for me to try once again... Looks like the second one will do... I will let you know as soon as I try... Thanks Peter!